# css files not load express-handlebars

Tags: css, express, reference, handlebars.js, workspace

I'm having trouble with the CSS acess using express-handlebars. I can't see the problem and I would like to have your help.

Here is my Workspace: 
[Workspace/Meus Arquivos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23LSS.jpg)

In my home.handlebars: `<link rel="stylesheet" href= "css/home.css">`

In my home.css:

> footer{
>       background-color: blue; }

Instead of showing a blue background as I ask for, it shows nothing:

Footer code:

```
    <footer>
    <font size = 4>
        <h5>© 2019 Suplementos Atlética</h5>
    </font>
</footer>
```

[Footer/Rodapé](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyzeO.jpg)

Comment: Show us some code please. At least the element that has class of footer. [ask]

Comment: Thanks for the commentary and I'm sorry for that. I did update.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In expresss, you have to set express static. It Will looks like this code below:

```js
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

> if your public folder is inside src folder use below method

```js
app.use(express.static("src/public"));
```

Now, you can create a `public` folder in your root app and `css` folder in your public folder and put your style into there.

So, your directory with looks like this:

- src
- public > css > home.css
- views

**How to use?** You can call your link like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "/css/home.css">
```

For an example, you can look at my example project here: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-fog-1n61o

Answer (score 1):

Create a base folder called  "public" then create a "css" folder, with your desired css files

Also in your index.js make sure you have the following:

```
    var app = express();
    //serve up your main public folder
    app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
    //set the layout engine your using
    app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
    // would render your home.handlebars page
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.render('home');
    });
```

Your public folder should have `css/home.css` and it should render inside your home page you created

Comment: Thank you a lot! Awesome help. I didn't have the folder. Actually, the app.use linecode that you wrote didn't work, but, as commented before, the app.use(express.static('public')); worked. Thank you a lot!